# Repeat SSRS report for each value in Dataset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an SSRS report with a subreport. 
Both, main report and subreport have @param1 parameters that are properly linked and the report runs just fine.

I also have a dataset (MemberDataSet) that returns all members of the certain group that are parameter values for param1.

For example, right now I'm running report three times say for parameters (@param1) AAA, BBB, and CCC.  MemberDataSet is querying for each individual group members and a simple query like

Select distinct Param1 from MyParamTable where Group = @GroupParameter

retruns AAA, BBB, and CCC values to be supplied as a parameter.

What I want to accomplish is to repeat the entire report, with it's subreport, for every value in dataset. i.e.

@Param1 = AAA
Run the report
@Param1 = BBB
Run/repeat the report (Append to previously generated report)
@Param1 = CCC
Run/repeat the report (Append to previously generated report).

What would be the best way of doing this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a wrapping data set "ABC" for values AAA, BBB, and CCC
2. Add "List" tablix to your page and assign "ABC" to it.
3. Put all content you want to repeat for each value within "ABC" inside of that list.
4. If you want to use sub-tables you can use only values from "ABC" in them.
5. If you want to repeat any other data sets you have to create sub-reports and pass values AAA, BBB, and CCC as parameters to those sub-reports.
   Hope it helps